# How to remove my punctuation array from original text

Tags: python, list

I have punctuation array like this

```
punctuation_data = [ '=' '+' '_' '-' ')' '(' '*' '&' '^' '%'
'SSSS' 'AAAA' 'wwww' '!' '~' '،']
```

and i have text to remove punctuation of this text, i use this but its not working

```
list = [''.join(c for c in original_data if c not in punctuation_data) 
for s in list]
```

Comment: Please provide the `original_data`, too so that others can reproduce

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Original post did not delete longer substrings. I included a function that loops through the punctuation data and deletes the substrings.

You need to separate your list by comma. Also, don't use predefined names like `list`.

This will work:

```
punctuation_data = [ '=', '+', '_', '-', ')', '(', '*', '&', '^', '%',
'SSSS', 'AAAA', 'wwww', '!', '~', '،']

orig_string = ['3+5=8']

def delete_substrings(orig_sub_string, punctuation_data):
    for element_to_delete in punctuation_data:
        orig_sub_string = orig_sub_string.replace(element_to_delete, "")
    return orig_sub_string

lst = [''.join(c for c in orig_sub_string if c not in punctuation_data) for orig_sub_string in orig_string]

print(lst) #['358']
```

Comment: This won't match any of the multi-character strings in `punctuation_data`.

Comment: @blhsing Exactly, how can i do that?

Comment: Using the `str.replace` method in a loop is rather inefficient since it requires scanning the entire string for as many times as the number of strings in `punctuation_data`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying match a number of strings of varying lengths, it's best to use regex instead. Escape the strings with `re.escape` first so that they don't get interpreted as special characters in regex:

```
import re
punctuation_data = [ '=', '+', '_', '-', ')', '(', '*', '&', '^', '%', 'SSSS', 'AAAA', 'wwww', '!', '~', '،']
print(re.sub('|'.join(map(re.escape, punctuation_data)), '', 'abc*xyzAAAA123'))
```

This outputs:

```
abcxyz123
```

Answer (score -1):

this is worked for me

```
original_data = 'What is hello'
punctuation_data = [ '=' '+' '_' '-' ')' '(' '*' '&' '^' 
'%'
'SSSS' 'AAAA' 'wwww' '!' '~' '،']
original_data = original_data.split()

resultwords  = [word for word in original_data if 
word.lower() not in punctuation_data]
result = ' '.join(resultwords)

print result
```